# How may I write a SYSTAT file from R?

Tags: r

I've successfully written DBF files using write.foreign from the 'foreign' package, e.g.:

```
write.dbf(df, "~/test.dbf")
```

Hoping to write a SYSTAT file for a colleague, The `write.foreign` package help rather unhelpfully gives me this:

> To add support for another package, eg Systat, create a function
>   writeForeignSystat with the same first three arguments as
>   write.foreign. This will be called from write.foreign when
>   package="Systat".

What does this mean? The package *reads* SYSTAT but I can't find a way to write it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the `foreign` package does not support writing `Systat` files, no one has written the code to do that. To get support for Systat, the mechanism that `foreign` uses is that **you** as a user write a function that does this. To be able to call that function though `write.foreign`, that function needs to have a specific set of input arguments, i.e. a specific interface (`df, datafile, codefile`). In addition, the name is also standardized like this:

```
writeForeign{package name}
```

If you package name is `Systat`, this translates to a function called `writeForeignSystat`.

To see how these functions typically work, you could have a look at the other functions that `foreign` already has, and mimic their behaviour. Alternatively, I would dump the data to a text file (e.g. a `csv` file) and read that into Systat (assuming that Systat can read `csv` files).

Comment: Excellent - I shall stop puzzling about this. SYSTAT can certainly read `.csv` and that is going to be enough for now.